# Installing nUnit with ASP.Net MVC 1.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, nunit

Does anyone have any advice/information on how to install nUnit with ASP.Net MVC? I have seen previous posts which related to the preview releases and involved a ghoulish nightmare of having to create template files, run command prompt and even mess with the registry.

Obviously this is far from ideal and given Microsoft's intention to allow any testing framework I was hoping that it was a much improved process in the full release. Googling seems to return results from when MVC was in the preview stage though! This is for Visual Studio 2008 Pro.

Cheers :)

**Edit: Seems maybe not:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381614.aspx

**Edit 2:**: Ok found this: http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/05/30/asp-net-mvc-preview-3-tooling-updates.aspx - They offer some templates and after installing the batch file it appears to show up in the drop down list when adding a new MVC application. However it was designed for the preview release of MVC so it's not ideal. Again, anyone who has better advice please post :)

Comment: Can you confirm which Visual Studio SKU you are using? VS 2008 Express Web, or Professional and above?

Comment: YMMV, but in my case, since I didn't find very detailed information about NUnit - MVC 1.0 integration, I ended up with xUnit.net, which works pretty well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Download it here](http://memphiswebtech.com/public/nunitprojecttemplate.zip) and follow the steps in the read me file to install it.

Here's the overview of how I did it.

1. Unzip the MVC test project template that comes with visual studio, MvcWebApplicationTestProjectTemplatev1.cs.zip.
2. Changed HomeController.cs and AccountController.cs files to the NUnit syntax, such as, [TestClass] to [TestFixture], etc....
3. Updated the references in MvcApplicationTest.csproj to for NUnit.Framework.
4. Tweaked the MvcWebApplicationTestProjectTemplate.cs.vstemplate file changing NamePackage, Description, Icon Package, and Defaut Name.

Once you get it zipped back up you will need to open up the Visual Studio Command Prompt and type devenv /setup to register the template with visual studio.

You will need to create a registry entry so visual studio knows where the new template lives.

If I ever get a blog I will be happy to update my answer with a detailed post.  It's a little involved to put it here...Goolish ain't the word :).

Answer (score 2):

ScottGu just released some [updated NUnit templates for ASP.NET MVC 1.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/04/28/updated-nunit-templates-for-asp-net-mvc-1-0-rtm.aspx).  All you need to do is run the enclosed **installNUnit.cmd** file.

Answer (score 2):

I have posted a guide and a update to Joe Cartano post on this, so that it works with MVC 2.0.

http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/11/17/nunit-templates-for-asp-net-mvc-2-0-preview-2/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just creating your own test project (with a reference to the MVC web app project) and manually adding the references you need to?  I did this because trying to have VS.Net try to create the test project for me never worked out all that well (then again, I was doing it before preview 3).  It's a minor PITA since I have to add using statements to every class I create in my test project, but it works.  No command prompts, no registry, none of that nonsense needed.

As an aside, [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/)'s test helpers are a godsend.

Comment: Yeah, Tbh I was looking for a quick and easy way to do it! I imagine I could just create my own project anyway, for each app.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Xunit havent got far enough to use it yet it installed fine 
I have to referance System.Routid and system.Web.Abstrations everytime