# Visual studio NUnit integration

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, nunit

For some project templates (ASP.NET MVC, WPF MVVM app...), Visual Studio 2008 prompts the user if he wants to create a test project :

[image]

However, in the list of test frameworks, only "Visual Studio Unit Test" is available. I'd like to be able to choose NUnit instead... Is this possible, and how ?

I installed TestDriven.NET, but it doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this thread will help

[Installing nUnit with ASP.Net MVC 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721038/installing-nunit-with-asp-net-mvc-1-0)

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting. I couldn't make it work yet, but it seems to be the right track